# Apache Geode : Improve query performance when order by clause is provided in the query

Tags: apache, geode

We are currently facing performance issues when order by clause is provided as a part of the query.

Current Specs:
We are running two geode servers with capacity of 20Gb(Max heap size) each. Geode has around 3.1 million records and the table has 1.48 million.

Query:

> query --query="SELECT  DISTINCT cashFlowId,upstreamSystem,upstreamSystemTxnDate,valueDate,amount,status FROM  WHERE AND account IN  SET ('XYZ','ABC') AND valueDate >= TO_DATE('20180320', 'yyyyMMdd') AND status = 'Booked' AND isActive = true AND category = 'Actual' ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 100"

The above query retrieves the output in 13-15 seconds after 2-3 times.

> Actual Result Set:  666553
>
> No of Records in the table: 1.49 million

What have we tried/observed so far?

1. We found that the index (type: range) is being picked correctly.
2. No improvement even after allocating more memory to JVM .
3. Verified that `IN` operator has no impact on the query performance. We tried the same using `OR` operator
4. On removing the `Order by` clause, the query gets completed in 2 seconds. We figured that sorting is eating most of the time.

Could you please guide or shed some information in improving the query performance?

Server Metrics:

```
Category  |        Metric         | Value
--------- | --------------------- | ------------
cluster   | totalHeapSize         | 47135
cache     | totalRegionEntryCount | 3100429
```

Comment: The internal implementation needs to create a lot of temporal objects to execute the actual comparison required by the `ORDER BY` clause. Probably the huge amount of temporal objects is causing more garbage and, because of that, more GCs need to be executed while the query is executing, thus slowing the overall performance. Have you checked GC executions and JVM pauses?.

Answer (score 0):

Like Urizen said, check the number of GC's going on but there is more. Here is the code and it looks fairly tight: [Geode Order By Comparator](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/develop/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/cache/query/internal/OrderByComparator.java).  There is another factor related to the nature of distributed sort order that has little to do with Geode as a product. Each node does its ordering but when the results get returned from each node, those results need to be merged with the results from other nodes. In other words, given a set of {2,4,3,1,6,5}, node 1 can sort {2,5,6} and node 2 sorts {1,3,4} but the controlling node needs to do a merge for you to get {1,2,3,4,5,6}.  I suspect that there's some of that going on as well.  This has nothing to do with Geode per se but just distributed order by's.   In database performance optimization theory, the database is the worst place to do an order by.

I'm wondering here if the better way to do this is to return 2 answer sets: 1) your answer set that you want but unsorted, and 2) a small KV collection of items where K is amount and V is the key.  Then on the client you do a sort of the small KV collection and iterate over the KV collection reading your larger answer set in that order.

If you didn't want to write a function to do that, you could do one additional query up front to select amount, key FROM ..., wrap that in a sorted collection and then do your full unsorted query. This should be really quick since your 2 seconds is partially being consumed by network on such a large answer set.

Jason may have some technical insights but removing the load from the server may be the answer if you have large answer sets like you do.